# Are tensor products cancellative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $F \subseteq k$ a subfield, and $A_0$ a finitely generated $F$-algebra.  Then $k \otimes_F A_0$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra.  If $B_0$ is another finitely generated $F$-algebra, and there exists some $k$-algebra isomorphism $\phi:k \otimes_F A_0 \rightarrow k \otimes_F B_0$, do $A_0$ and $B_0$ have to be isomorphic as $F$-algebras?  Or at least $F$-vector spaces?

I know that if $\phi$ were induced by some existing homomorphism $A_0 \rightarrow B_0$, then the claim would follow from faithful flatness.  If $\phi$ is any old isomorphism, I'm not so sure.  What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand what the title of the question has to do with the body.

Comment: I just meant with a product, if you have $A \times B \cong A \times C$, then $B$ has to be isomorphic to $C$.  But that might not be true either now that I think about it

Comment: No, that's not true (even for sets: take $A$ to be empty).

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan What if we assume $A$ is not initial?

Comment: @silvascientist: there are still counterexamples in many familiar categories, but they're a bit harder to write down. A keyword to search for is "cancellation problem." There are also easy counterexamples in any poset regarded as a category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, let $k = \mathbb{R}, F = \mathbb{C}$. The $\mathbb{R}$-algebras $\mathbb{H}$ and $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ are nonisomorphic, but both of them complexify to $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. For a commutative example, $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ both complexify to $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$.

If $k \to F$ is a Galois extension, then questions of this form fall under the heading of what is called **Galois descent**. If $A$ is an $F$-algebra, then $k$-algebras $A_0$ such that $A_0 \otimes_k F \cong A$ are called **$k$-forms** of $A$, and in general these need not either exist or be unique.

Comment: I swapped the roles of $k$ and $F$ here from what they were in the OP. In my defense, it's weird to use the capital letter to denote the smaller field.